# How to detect method calls made by Python behind the scenes?

Tags: python

In particular, I want to see which magic method is being called by a particular line of code.

For instance, I know that `1 + 2` actually calls `(1).__add__(2)` and `[1,2,3][0]` calls `[1,2,3].__getitem__(0)`.

I'd like to know which magic methods are called for other operations without having to look it up online.

Comment: use the `dis` module to get the opcode for the operation and then you can dig through `ceval.c` in the source code, which has a big switch on opcodes, to see where that takes you, but this can be non-trivial, depending on the operation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There isn't a good way to inspect that. You should probably just look it up.

In the implementation (specifically for CPython), `1 + 2` or `[1, 2, 3][0]` won't actually go through the `__add__` or `__getitem__` methods at all; they'll go through C-level hooks and skip the methods entirely. Even if they went through the methods, it'd all happen in C-level code, which you can't debug with PDB or do much of anything to inspect.

The closest I have to something matching the spirit of what you're looking for is

```
>>> import unittest.mock
>>> unittest.mock.MagicMock() + 3
<MagicMock name='mock.__add__()' id='140290799397408'>
```

so hey, look! `+` uses `__add__`. That's something you can run to see what magic method is invoked for `+`. It doesn't involve actually inspecting the magic methods involved in `+`, though. `MagicMock` just has already-written implementations of most of the standard magic methods.